# Display (mntr) DeviceID Mac OS X in Bash?

Tags: bash

I need to query the DeviceID of each connected monitor on Mac OS X Leopard & Snow Leopard. is this possible to do using bash? if not what would be the best approach?
would this be stored in a preference file anywhere?

i tried accessing the system_profiler info but it does not look like the device id is included for the monitors.

any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: No, unfortunately i can't see the device ID here. I can find it by opening ColorSync Utility and looking at devices manually though...

Answer (score 3):

You can find here [How to Get the Display Name with the Display ID in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236498/how-to-get-the-display-name-with-the-display-id-in-mac-os-x/4677759#4677759) one small C program. You can compile it, and when you run it will show Device ID.

For example, for my notebook will return:

```
Color LCD : 69677760
```

it is decimal number, when you convert it to hexadecimal

```
echo 69677760 16 o p | dc
```

will return the 42732C0 hex-number what is the last part of Device ID from the colorsync.