# Casting a CFDictionaryRef to NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, casting, nsdictionary

I have the code (stripped down):

```
CFDictionaryRef *currentListingRef;
//declare currentListingRef here
NSDictionary *currentListing;
currentListing = (NSDictionary *) currentListingRef;
```

And then I get the error:

> Cast of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'CFDictionaryRef *' (aka 'const
>   struct __CFDictionary **') to 'NSDictionary *' is disallowed with ARC

What am I doing wrong? How do I convert from a `CFDictionaryRef` to an `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

ARC changed the way bridging works.

```
NSDictionary *original = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"World" forKey:@"Hello"];
CFDictionaryRef dict = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)original;
NSDictionary *andBack = (__bridge NSDictionary*)dict;
NSLog(@"%@", andBack);
```

Comment: How would this work the other way? As in, make 'myNSDictionary' from 'cfDict'?

Comment: I tried: `currentListing = (__bridge NSDictionary *) currentListingRef;` and received the error of: **"Incompatible types casting 'CFDictionaryRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFDictionary **') to 'NSDictionary *' with a __bridge cast"**

Comment: updated the answer with how to go both ways. The problem with your code is you have CFDictionarRef*, CFDictionaryRef is already a pointer type.

Answer (score 9):

In ARC, this should be done this way:

```
CFDictionaryRef currentListingRef = ...;
NSDictionary *currentListing = CFBridgingRelease(currentListingRef);
```

This releases the CF object and transfers ownership of the object to ARC
otherwise you should release CF object manually.

Comment: CFBridgingRelease is correct, assuming that "..." means you created/copied a CFDictionaryRef. While this is most likely the case, you don't always want to transfer

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
NSDictionary *ssidList = (__bridge NSDictionary*)myDict;
NSString *SSID = [ssidList valueForKey:@"SSID"];
```