# Casting CFDictionaryRef with pointer?

Tags: ios, ios4, casting, ftp, nsdictionary

I have the code (simplified):

```
#define kSendBufferSize 32768
UInt8 listingBuffer[kSendBufferSize];
NSDictionary *currentListing; 
CFIndex bufferLength;
CFDictionaryRef currentListingRef;
CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(kCFAllocatorDefault, listingBuffer, bufferLength, currentListingRef);
currentListing = (__bridge NSDictionary *) currentListingRef;
```

on the last line, I receive the following warning in XCode:

```
"Incompatible pointer types passing 'CFDictionaryRef' (aka 'const struct __CFDictionary *')
 to parameter of type 'CFDictionaryRef *' (aka const struct __CFDictionary **')"
```

The problem is that I need to declare the CFDictionaryRef with no pointer so that this line will work properly: (see [Casting a CFDictionaryRef to NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018497/casting-a-cfdictionaryref-to-nsdictionary))

```
currentListing = (__bridge NSDictionary *) currentListingRef;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own answer through another forum. The key is to use the `&` operator when passing the `CFDictionaryRef` through the `CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing`. For example:

```
CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(kCFAllocatorDefault, listingBuffer, bufferLength, &currentListingRef);
```