# Delphi on OSX: how to convert CFDictionaryRef to NSDictionary?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677) `CFDictionaryRef` and `NSDictionary` are `Toll-Free Bridged Types`.
However, I get an AV in the following code, which MIGHT be because the bridge does not work with Delphi.

`DADiskCopyDescription` returns a `CFDictionaryRef`, which I wrap to a `NSDictionary`. The pointer is not NIL, but when I access a function in the object, I get an AV:

```
function osxGetRootVolumeUUID: string;
var lNSDictionary: NSDictionary;
    lDisk: DADiskRef;
    lCFUrl: CFURLRef;
    lSession: DASessionRef;
    lUUID: CFUUIDRef;
begin
  result := '';
  lSession := DASessionCreate(nil);
  lCFUrl := TNSURL.OCClass.fileURLWithPath(StrToNSStr('/'));
  lDisk := DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(nil,lSession,lCFUrl);
  lNSDictionary := TNSDictionary.Wrap(DADiskCopyDescription(lDisk));

  lUUID := lNSDictionary.objectForKey(kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey); //<- AV here

  if lUUID<>nil then
    result := CFStringRefToStr( CFUUIDCreateString(nil, lUUID));
  lNSDictionary.release;
  CFRelease(lCFurl);
end;
```

I also tried to use `CFBridgingRelease` as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018497/casting-a-cfdictionaryref-to-nsdictionary) but it gives error `SIGABRT (6)`:

```
lNSDictionary := TNSDictionary.Wrap(CFBridgingRelease(DADiskCopyDescription(lDisk))); //gives error: SIGABRT (6)
```

How to make it work?

PS. Basically I just want to get the `UUID` of the root volume on OSX. The function above is converted to Delphi from an Objective-C function we have used so far.

**Edit**

Another thing I have tried is to avoid using `NSDictionary`, but this gives an error too, which could indicate that the problem is something else:

```
lCFDictionaryRef := DADiskCopyDescription(lDisk);
lUUID := CFDictionaryGetValue(lCFDictionaryRef, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey); //<- AV here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a CFDictionaryRef to a TNSDictionary you must do it like this :

```
  var LNSDict: NSDictionary;
      LCFDict: CFDictionaryRef;

  LCFDict := DADiskCopyDescription(lDisk);
  try
    LNSDict:= TNSDictionary.Wrap(LCFDict );
  finally
    CFRelease(LCFDict);
  end;
```

so everything is good here, however i think maybe your av is in the way you access the object. don't forget in IOS to always use getObjectID and not the pointer to the object

ex: pass to ios api `(xxx as ILocalObject).GetObjectID` and never pass to the IOS api directly `xxx`

so maybe it's must be `(kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey as ILocalObject).GetObjectID` or something similar

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey cannot be typecasted to iLocalObject ([dccosx Error] uOSXutils.pas(136): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type). kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey is generated by SDKtransform and I think it can be passed directly.

Comment: I just found that "(kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey as ILocalObject).GetObjectID" was in fact the solution. The reason it did not work in the first place was that `kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey` is implemented wrong in `Macapi.DiskArbitration`. When I implement it using `CocoaNSStringConst` instead of `CocoaPointerConst` then it works.